# Gnuplot use parts of date column / divide by days

Tags: time, gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

```
30/11/2012 600.00
31/12/2012 620.00
31/01/2013 640.00
28/02/2013 580.00
31/03/2013 720.23
30/04/2013 710.26
31/05/2013 800.54
30/06/2013 786.58
31/07/2013 821.82
31/08/2013 854.91
30/09/2013 849.17
31/10/2013 910.26
```

I would like to plot this data, having column 1 as the x-axis, and on the y-axis: "column 2 divided by the days in column 1". But I don't know how to extract the days.
This is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work, i.e. I get exactly the same graph as plotting 1 against 2:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y"
plot 'data.csv' u 1:($2/tm_mday($1)) w l
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Nice question.  Had me stumped for a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this can't possibly be the expected behavior, but for your particular situation (since the date is first), you can do:

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:($2/$1) w l
```

e.g.:

```
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt '%d/%m/%Y'
gnuplot> set term dumb
Terminal type set to 'dumb'
Options are 'feed  size 79, 24'
gnuplot> plot 'test.dat' u 1:($2/$1) w l



  30 +++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+++
     +     +     +     +    +     +     +    'test.dat' u 1:($2/$1) ********
  29 ++                                                                ***++
     |                                                              ***    |
  28 ++                                                          ***      ++
     |                                                        ***          |
  27 ++                                                    ***            ++
     |                                          ***********                |
  26 ++                                      ***                          ++
  25 ++                                     *                             ++
     |                                    **                               |
  24 ++                                  *                                ++
     |                               ****                                  |
  23 ++                           ***                                     ++
     |                           *                                         |
  22 ++                        **                                         ++
     |                        *                                            |
  21 ++                      *                                            ++
     +     +     +  *********     +     +     +     +    +     +     +     +
  20 +++-+-*********-+-+-+-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-++-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+++
 01/11/12/12/12/01/13/02/1303/13/04/13/05/13/06/13/07/1308/13/09/13/10/13/11/13
```

Rational:  I believe that the `set xdata time` clause really only applies to the first part of the using specification.  When you hit the second part of the using specification (`$2/$1`), gnuplot is back to interpreting everything as normal.  The normal using parser is pretty forgiving, so when it sees `30/11/2012`, it only takes the stuff it knows how to handle -- the `30` -- and silently ignores the rest.

---

Working on the above hypothesis<sup>1</sup>, I came up with this:

```
plot 'test.dat' u 1:($2/tm_mday(strptime('%d/%m/%Y', strcol(1)))) w l
```

First, we need to tell gnuplot that the stuff in column 1 is a string (`strcol(1)`) which we then read as a time based on our time format (`strptime( ... )`).  Finally, you can use the `tm_mday` function on it since strptime did all the hard work of getting the data into the format that `tm_mday` requires.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note that my above hypothesis also explains the behavior that you see in the original.  If `$1` is always returning the day portion of the string, then `tm_mday` is always seeing a number between 1 and 31.  Since `tm_mday` expects an argument as seconds since Jan 1, 2000, the day is always `1` (e.g. Jan **1**, 2000 plus ~30 seconds.).  So, dividing by it doesn't make any difference in the plot.</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure I'd ever used the dumb terminal before this ... My new laptop doesn't have any reasonable interactive terminals installed, so `dumb` seemed like the best option ...

Comment: Fantastic explanation @mgilson - I can't believe I hadn't tried $2/$1. The 'dumb' output looks good enough, learned something again :-)